# Generate exactly 1 Flowfile

Tags: apache-nifi, flowfile

I'm using the `GenerateFlowFile` processor in Apache Nifi - When I activate it, I want the processor to create exactly `1` Flowfile.

Right now I use the REST API via Python to change the state to `RUNNING`, wait `0.5` seconds and change the state to `STOPPED`. This results in `1` FlowFile being added to the queue to the next processor.

I tested a bit and waiting for `1.5` seconds gives me `2` FlowFiles, `2.5` seconds gives me `3` FlowFiles - I'm guessing the processor generates one Flowfile each second it is running.

**How can I ensure that exactly `1` Flowfile is being generated?** The above method obviously is dependent on the network connection and roundtrip times. Worst case: the connection drops while I wait and I cannot stop the processor anymore and x Flowfiles are being generated.

My current configs are:

Settings:

```
Yield duration: 1 sec
Penalty Duration: 30sec
Bulletin Level: WARN
```

Scheduling:

```
Scheduling Strategy: CRON driven 
Concurrent Tasks: 1 
Run Schedule: * * * * * ?
Execution: All nodes
Run duration: 0ms
```

Properties:

```
File Size: 0B
Batch Size: 1
Data Format: Text
Unique FlowFiles: false
Custom Text: No value set
Character Set: UTF-8
Mime Type: No value set
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to flag the GenerateFlowFile as Primary node only (assuming you have more than 1 node) to ensure each node is not generating its own FlowFile.

Set the Scheduling to Timer and whack the run schedule up to something like 604800 (1 week) - this means that it even if you leave the processor running, it's only going to run once a week - that should give you plenty time to fix a connectivity issue if your script can't connect to tell the processor to stop.

Keep concurrency at 1.